# FileUpload.HasFile property is always false,While File Upload is place inside GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have Tab Container, and i have a GridView inside that. I need to upload image while i am clicking on the particular row. I am using update Panel too, outside of the grid view, i was able to upload image using PostBack Trigger to "preview Button", but inside gridview i don know how to access it. I just created one button called btngrvPreview outside of the gridview and called its click event to the button btnPreview1 which is placed inside gridView. I think this approach is correct only.. But i don know why this Trigger to btnPreview1 is not working.

Its showing if(vFile.HasFile ) condition is always getting false..

Help me to solve this problem.

**GridView**

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grvItem" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="grvItem_RowDataBound"                                                ShowFooter="True" SkinID="grid" Width="100%">  
    <Columns>                 
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Reference&nbsp;ID" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Design">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="grvlbldesign" runat="server" CssClass="lbl">
    </asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>                 
    </asp:TemplateField>     
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Upload Image">
    <ItemTemplate>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hifgrvImage" runat="server" />
    <a ID="grvuploadimgPopup" runat="server">
    <asp:Image ID="grvUploadImage" runat="server" Width="90px" />
    </a>                                                                                 </ItemTemplate>             
    <EditItemTemplate>                                                                   
    <asp:FileUpload ID="fupImage1" runat="server" CssClass="fileuploadbtn" TabIndex="5" ToolTip="Browse For Image" Width="152px"/>         
    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnPreview1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/view.gif" TabIndex="5" ToolTip="Preview" onclick="btngrvPreview_Click"/>
  </EditItemTemplate>                                                                        
</asp:TemplateField>     
    <Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btngrvPreview" />                   
    </Triggers>
```

**Button Click EVent**

```
protected void btnPreview1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
 {
  try
     {
            int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(hifRecordID.Value);
            Image vimgView = (Image)grvItem.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("grvUploadImage");
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload vFile = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload)grvItem.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("fupImage1");

            string strimage;
            string strfilename, strextn;
            if (vFile.HasFile)
            {
                System.IO.Path.GetExtension(vFile.FileName);
                string strfileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(vFile.FileName).ToLower();
                string[] strAllowedFileExtensions = { ".gif", ".jpeg" };
                if (strfileExtension == ".jpeg")
                    strfileExtension = ".gif";
                if (FileExtensionIsApproved(strfileExtension) == true)
                {
                    strfilename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(vFile.PostedFile.FileName);
                    strextn = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(strfilename);
                    strimage = ObjDataAccess.LoginName + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfffffff") + strextn;
                    ViewState["Filename"] = strimage;
                    string strpath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ITEMPHOTO"] + strimage;
                    //Server.MapPath("empphoto") + "\\" + strimage;

                    vFile.PostedFile.SaveAs(strpath);
                    if (hifimgbrowser.Value == "IE")
                    {
                        vimgView.ImageUrl = strpath;
                        // tstimg.HRef = vimgView.ImageUrl;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        vimgView.ImageUrl = "~/Handler.ashx?id=" + strpath;
                        // tstimg.HRef = imgView.ImageUrl;
                    }
                    vimgView.Visible = true;
                    System.IO.Stream fs = vFile.PostedFile.InputStream;
                    byte[] bytMyData = new byte[fs.Length + 1];
                    fs.Read(bytMyData, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
                    fs.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    // DeleteImageFile();
                    vimgView.ImageUrl = "";
                    //  tstimg.HRef = "";
                    vimgView.Visible = true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            strMsg = ex.Message;
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "alertScript", "showMsgbox('" + strMsg + "','','2','');", true);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the asp:FileUpload control is inside an UpdatePanel it must not trigger an asynchronous post back as it will not post the file.

Comment: FileUpload control is inside updatepanel only,and i didt use asynchronous postback, i just used <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btngrvPreview" /> what else i have to add in that?

Comment: Make sure UpdatePanel is set to only post back conditionally and the FileUpload control is causing synchronous postback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you debug, and make sure that findcontrol method is not returning null, and also you place fileupload control in EditTemplate, so you have to check in this way in GridView _PreRender events

```
if (this.GridView1.EditIndex != -1)
   {
     FileUpload upload = GridView1.Rows[GridView1.EditIndex].FindControl("fupImage1") as Button;
     if (upload != null)
      {
      //do something
      }
   }
```

may be this will help you...

Comment: I have tried Ur code, its not returning null, returning {System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload} control.. but the FileName is empty. Before also Same problem i was getting.